# Is there any way I can run Azure PowerShell cmdlets using Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-powershell

Is there any way I can run Azure PowerShell cmdlets using Visual Studio ?

I would like to perform the same activities which can be performed using azure powershell ISE.

Answer (score 2):

Not natively.  But, there is a Visual Studio plugin available that will accomplish this.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c9eb3ba8-0c59-4944-9a62-6eee37294597